# Heroku: Django backend is not working, getting error GET http://localhost:8000/api/todos/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, django, heroku

I actually created a fullstack todo app with django as backend and react as frontend. The frontend is working perfectly fine, you can that here -> https://ym-todo-application.herokuapp.com. But somehow my application cannot connect to the django backend, also on inspecting on browser i saw this error -> GET http://localhost:8000/api/todos/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Containing lot of files and code so i pushed them on bitbucket to make it easier to debug. here's the link https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/todo-app-fullstack/src/master/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be an issue with your deployment. Refer this guide on how to deploy a React and Django app: https://dev.to/shakib609/deploy-your-django-react-js-app-to-heroku-2bck

Comment: in settings.py change ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1',] add the ip of your server

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe i followed the tutorial you mentioned previously as well but it gives me error when i try to install django-heroku using poetry. Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Where is your backend hosted? `http://localhost:8000/api/todos/` this is not the address of your backend. There should be URL where you can reach your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the REST API server address. The `localhost:8000` is the server address used in the development.

What is more, I see in your code that each time you write the request you have hard-coded server URL. You don't need to do this. You can set the server address by setting `baseURL`:

```
import axios from "axios";
if (window.location.origin === "http://localhost:3000") {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"; // development address
} else {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin; // production address
}
```

Then in the request, you only write the endpoint address, example:

```
axios.put(`/api/todos/${item.id}/`, item)
```

Please see my article [Docker-Compose for Django and React with Nginx reverse-proxy and Let's Encrypt certificate](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/) for more details about Django and React deployment.

Comment: i updated my bitbucket repository, i noticed the frontend part was completely different. The mistake is fixed now. Also, im still confused a little do i need to put the localhost: 8000 inside the square brackets of Allowed hosts of settings.py file? is that what you want me to do ?

Comment: Does the answer fix your problem or not? If the app is working you don't need to update `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: to answer your question i need to know in which file specifically do i need to make changes? so that i can tell if your answer helped me or not. Also i updated the code because the previous one was having a different app.js file and todo_project folder (a different project with same code, my bad). I will accept your answer if it helps i promise.

Comment: Sorry! Didnt know that. Please add the setting in app.js code at line 6. This is how it is done in my project: https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate/blob/main/frontend/src/App.js

Comment: Here is my `settings.py` https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate/blob/main/backend/server/server/settings.py - just in case, I've checked your `settings.py` and it looks OK.

Comment: i made changes as you mentioned but still the same issue. The changes i made i also updated them in repository, in case if i missed something so you can check, here's the link https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/todo-app-fullstack/src/master/